# Matplotlib Legend in a Loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to have the legend add an entry for each item that gets plotted in the loop. So, there may be 6 times that a 'vgs' gets plotted, and for each one I want to add an entry for the name 'vgs' and the color that was plotted for that specific instance of 'vgs'. My code seems to currently create a legend for the last instance.

```
for n in range(len(eventBreakL)):
    if n < len(eventBreakL)-1:
        eventL = c_eventConditionL[eventBreakL[n]:eventBreakL[n+1]-1]
        tL,isubL,vgsL,vdsL = [],[],[],[]
        for m in eventL:
            tL.append(m[1])
            isubL.append(m[-1])
            vdsL.append(m[2])
            vgsL.append(m[3])
        c_isub_plot.plot(tL,isubL,'o')
        vgs=vgvd_plot.plot(tL,vgsL,'o')
        vds=vgvd_plot.plot(tL,vdsL,'o')
vgvd_plot.legend((vds, vgs), ('vds', 'vgs'), loc='best')
```

Is there a way to get the legend to append each new instance that's plotted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i=0
for n in range(len(eventBreakL)):
    if n < len(eventBreakL)-1:
        i+=1
        eventL = c_eventConditionL[eventBreakL[n]:eventBreakL[n+1]-1]
        tL,isubL,vgsL,vdsL = [],[],[],[]
        for m in eventL:
            tL.append(m[1])
            isubL.append(m[-1])
            vdsL.append(m[2])
            vgsL.append(m[3])
        c_isub_plot.plot(tL,isubL,label=str(i))
        c_isub_plot.legend()
        vgvd_plot.plot(tL,vgsL,label=str(i))
        vgvd_plot.plot(tL,vdsL,label=str(i))
        vgvd_plot.legend()
```